# Matching strings to components React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm making a Calendar which consists of an `header` and `calendar`. The `header` is for picking the type of calendar; `weekly` or `monthly`.

I had to make a dummy component called `CalendarPicker` just so I can use a `switch`. Inline switch is what I think needed but jsx doesn't accept it.

Is there a better way to do this? Or another way to match strings to components?

```
 <CalendarController
        render={({ type, onTypeClick }) => (
          <>
            <header>
              <p>header of agenda</p>
              <button onClick={onTypeClick("weekly")}>weekly</button>
              <button onClick={onTypeClick("monthly")}>monthly</button>
            </header>

            <CalendarPicker
              type={type}
              render={type => {
                switch (this.props.type) {
                  case "monthly":
                    return <MonthlyCalendar />;
                  case "weekly":
                    return <WeeklyCalendar />;
                  default:
                    return <MonthlyCalendar />;
                }
              }}
            />
          </>
        )}
      />
```

Comment: *"but jsx doesn't accept it."* what does that mean? what is `this.props.type`? Sure that it's not `switch (type) {`?

Comment: *"Or another way to match strings to components"*  `{type === "weekly"? <WeeklyCalendar />: <MonthlyCalendar />}`

Answer (score 0):

This is what I did to achieve this. In my case there were around 50 components and according to the name in the string I had to render that component.

I created a file ComponentSelector.js which imports all the components.

**ComponentSelector.js**

```
export default const objComponents = {
       MonthlyCalendar : {
    LoadComponent: function () {
        return require('../../Modules/MonthlyCalendar ').default;
    }
   },
  WeeklyCalendar : {
    LoadComponent: function () {
        return require('../../Modules/WeeklyCalendar ').default;
    }
   }
 }
```

Import it into your CalendarController component

```
  import objComponents  from './ComponentSelector.js';

   render(){
        var CalComp=objComponents[this.props.type].LoadComponent();
        return(<div>
                <header>
                <p>header of agenda</p>
                <button onClick={onTypeClick("weekly")}>weekly</button>
                <button onClick={onTypeClick("monthly")}>monthly</button>
                </header>
                <CalComp type={type}/>
             </div>)
   }
```